# Give the values of "a" where the linear system has no solutions. Using Gauss elimination.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am having problems trying to row reduce this matrix. Particularily because of the zero in the first row. Could someone help me? I am not allowed to calculate the values of a using the determinant. I was having a bit of problems with latex so I will just write the system in text. I already made it into an augmented matrix.

$$x - 3z = -3 \\ 2x + ay -1 = -2 \\x + 2y + az = -1$$

Answer (score 3):

We are going to use Gauss elimination. Suppose for now $a\ne0$.
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\2&a&-1&-2\\1&2&a&-1\end{matrix}\right)&\xrightarrow{Row(2)\rightarrow Row(2)-2Row(1)}\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\0&a&5&4\\1&2&a&-1\end{matrix}\right)\\
&\xrightarrow{Row(3)\rightarrow Row(3)-Row(1)\ \ }\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\0&a&5&4\\0&2&a+3&2\end{matrix}\right)\\
&\xrightarrow{Row(3)\rightarrow a Row(3)-2Row(2)}\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\0&a&5&4\\0&0&a^2+3a-10&2a-8\end{matrix}\right).\\
\end{align}
$a^2+3a-10=0$ for $a=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{49}}{2}$, and so for $a=-5$ or $a=2$ the third equation has no solution and so the system has no solution.

Suppose now $a=0$; then
\begin{align}
\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\2&0&-1&-2\\1&2&0&-1\end{matrix}\right)&\xrightarrow{Row(2)\rightarrow Row(2)-2Row(1)}\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\0&0&5&4\\1&2&0&-1\end{matrix}\right)\\
&\xrightarrow{Row(3)\rightarrow Row(3)-Row(1)\ \ }\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\0&0&5&4\\0&2&3&2\end{matrix}\right)\\
&\xrightarrow{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ Row(2)\longleftrightarrow Row(3)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ }\left(\begin{matrix}1&0&-3&-3\\0&2&3&2\\0&0&5&4\end{matrix}\right).\\
\end{align}
And so the system has solution for $a=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of multiplying a row by "a".